# ng-paste not working in angular2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to prevent pasting into a textbox using ng-paste in angular2 by cancelling the paste event. I got this to work in angularJS but not in angular2. Am I doing something wrong or does it not work in angular2?

```
<input type="text" #username class="form-control" id="username" required 
placeholder="Username" value="{{userName}}" ng-paste="$event.preventDefault()">
```

Comment: The syntax looks wrong, where did you get this event from? did you mean `(paste)="$event.preventDefault()">`

Comment: Yes...that's correct. I was using the directive from AngularJS, not Angular2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `(paste)="$event.preventDefault()"` or `(paste)="false"`.

Comment: That fixed my problem. Thanks a lot!